# Shared preferences and order

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I'm new to Android and I know I'm not really good and this might not be the best way of doing but I'm spending way too much time on this.

**Context :** 
ActivityA has a listA and a listB (both with custom object) and a gridview. ListA does a JSON request and is filled with everything the response gives. ListB only has listA.get(0).
The gridviewA displays listA. Every custom object has a "installed" boolean.
When I click on the item in the gridviewA (so, listA.get(0) = listB.get(0)), it starts a new ActivityB which displays in another gridviewB all of listA's items. When I click on one of those item, it is added into listB (installed is set to true).
Items in gridViewA have a button which deletes the item from gridViewA, from listB and from sharedPreferences (installed is set to false).

**What I want :**
Once I click in one of the ActivityB item, I want it to be a added to my sharedPreferences BUT I want my application to remember in which order I added each item.

**What I did :**
As sharedPreferences are Sets, I thought "why not add an ID at the begining of the sharedPrefs key, then I'll know which one to display in gridviewA".
That works fine, but a problem comes when I remove some items and try to readd other, the item will be in the other way around.

Example :

I "installed" 4 items, gridviewA looks like this :

V  |  W

X  |  Y

Z

Sharedprefs look like this (the number is the amount of "installed" objects) :

0_V = V // 1_W = W // 2_X = X // 3_Y = Y // 4_Z = Z

Let's say I remove item X and Y, gridview will be like this :

V  |  W

Z

Sharedprefs look like this :

0_V = V // 1_W = W // 4_Z = Z

Now let's say I add item X again, gridview will look like :

V  |  W

X  |  Z

and sharedPref like this :

0_V = V // 1_W = W // 4_Z = Z // 3_X = X

**Question is :**

How can I save the order in which I added things into Shared Preferences so I can display things in the correct order ?

**Code :**

```
in ActivityA
//reads the sharedpreferences to know which widget has been installed
for (int i = 0; i < listA.size(); i++)
{
    for (Map.Entry<String, ?> entry : keys.entrySet())
    {
        if (entry.getKey().startsWith(String.valueOf(i)))
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < listA.size(); j++)
            {
                if (listA.get(j).getName().equals(entry.getValue()) && !listA.get(j).isInstalled())
                    {
                            listA.get(j).setInstalled(true);
                            if (listA.get(j).isInstalled())
                            {
                                listB.add(listWidget.get(j));

                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Adapter of gridviewA :

```
holder.delete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
{
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
        Map<String, ?> keys = ActivityA.sharedPrefService.getAll();
        for (int i = 0; i < ActivityA.listA.size(); i++)
        {
                if (ActivityA.listA.get(i).getName().equals(listB.get(position).getName()))
                {
                ActivityA.listA.get(i).setInstalled(false);

                for (int j = 0; j <= listA.size(); j++)
                {

                    keys = ActivityA.sharedPrefService.getAll();
                    for (Map.Entry<String, ?> entry : keys.entrySet())
                        {
                            if (entry.getKey().equals(j + "_" + listA.get(i).getName()))
                            {
                                ActivityA.editorService.remove(j + "_" + listA.get(i).getName());
                                ActivityA.editorService.commit();                           
                            }
                    }
                }

                listB.remove(position);
                notifyDataSetChanged();
                break;
            }
        }
    }
});
```

And ActivityB when clicking on an item to install it

```
    if (!ActivityA.listA.get(position).isInstalled())
    {
        // As we allow the user to install several widget before going back to ActivityMain
        // we have to directly modify ActivityA.listA and ActivityA.listB
        ActivityA.listA.get(position).setInstalled(true);
        ActivityA.listB.add(ActivityA.listA.get(position));


        String temp = listA.get(position).getName();

        int order = -1;
        for(int i=0; i<ActivityA.listA.size(); i++)
        {
            if(ActivityA.listA.get(i).isInstalled())
            {
                order++;
            }
        }

        ActivityA.editorService.putString(order + "_" +temp, temp);
        ActivityA.editorService.commit();

        keys = ActivityA.sharedPrefService.getAll();
        }
```

Worst part is I'm pretty sure there's a very simple way of doing this but I just can't seem to find it.

Thanks for any feedback :)

Comment: Option 1: Use current time instead of an ID. Option 2: Remember last used ID in an additional preference and always take it and increment it when new item is added. Option 3: If possible number of added items is small, save them as a list in a single preference entry

Comment: @Michael Butscher Option 1: I would've to iterate through the dates then ? I don't think I really understand what you mean.
Option 2 : Im gonna try that first.
Option 3 : I've look at that a bit and I found that I had to create a list of map and add each item in a new map in the list, then save the list, right ?

Comment: Ok it works fine, but isn't it bad for performance if I'm doing many loops up to 100 if there're only 3 installed objects ?
Since the index keeps being incremented every time something is installed, it could potentially be very very high

Comment: Probably a more thorough code change is needed. One way can be to process each preference key only once by splitting it into ID and name part and then compare only the name part when deleting an entry. For installing in the right order, collect all keys in a list and sort them with a `Comparator` which again splits into parts and use the ID part for comparing